# Equivalent for WHERE clause using Eloquent function

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

i want to rewrite the following SQL statement into an Eloquent Format:

```
    SELECT `id`, `pushbadge`, `pushalert`, `pushsound`
    FROM `devices`
    WHERE `id` IN (1, 2, 3)
        AND `status`='active'"
```

My thought was

```
public function getDevicesWithIDs($ids) {

    $conditions = array();
    foreach($ids as $id) {
        $conditions[] = ['id' => $id];
    }
    var_dump($conditions);

    return Device::where($conditions)->get();
}
```

But this returns:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 
Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: select * from `devices` where (`0` = 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `$ids` is an array

you can get your result with something as below

`Device::whereIn('id', $ids)->where('status', 'active')->get(['id', 'pushbadge', 'pushalert', 'pushsound']);`